# Yahoo Messenger has gone completely purple, how do I make it white again?

Tags: yahoo-messenger

My Yahoo Messenger (current version v11) has gone completely purple. How do I make it white again?

I've just uninstalled it and installed version 10 from [oldversion.com](http://oldversion.com/).

I'm hoping though that Yahoo Messenger – somewhere in the current version, v11 – has an option to  enable the white background again. V10 still has a purple background at the top but it's generally white background.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that app, but have you looked for appearance settings in Options or Settings?

Comment: @music2myear yes of course, but I don't see the option to change the background colour. And yes I know you probably can't help further if you're not familiar with the app. Perhaps somebody that knows where options are e.g. because they've seen it!!, will then be able to tell me where the option is, if it exists.

Comment: click <messenger> <preferences> <change skin> and select something else